# Anchor link onclick run jquery plugin function with parameter

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have table with anchor to delete values. So when I click anchor it should pass parameter(id) and show confirm dialog. This is how I'm using anchor link

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteInitialize('.$id.');" class="confirmation-callback"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="delete_row"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></a>
```

Script I'm using

```
function deleteInitialize(data){
    $('.confirmation-callback').confirmation({
        placement:'left',
        onConfirm: function() { alert(data) },
        onCancel: function() { alert('cancel') }
    });
}
```

This currently not working properly. Properly in the sense it works if I click twice on the link. I know I'm doing this wrong. If anyone can suggest better way to do this that would be a huge help.

This is the fidle i created.
http://jsfiddle.net/qk1b1tgz/3/
But I want to pass id to this confirmation function.

Comment: From which plugin is `.confirmation()`?

Comment: So how do wanted it to work??

Comment: This is the plugin I'm using :https://github.com/Tavicu/bootstrap-confirmation

Comment: @Indrasinh Bihola when anchor click i want to pass parameter to $('.confirmation-callback').confirmation function and inside run callback accordingly

Comment: @Indrasinh Bihola http://jsfiddle.net/qk1b1tgz/3/

Comment: @Dushan take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sb4yq8o5/1/) to see how it can be done.